# How to call a method with return type as BOOL after Delay?

Tags: ios, delay

I have 3 conditions to be implemented as follows,

```
if(condition 1)
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   if(condition 2 )
   {
       //after 10 sec delay call condition 3 which will return BOOL value 
       retutn that BOOL value after 10 sec
   }
   else
   {
     return false;
   }
}
```

How to get BOOL value as a return type after delay?

Comment: in this case run all this condition after a delay.

Comment: I don't see any reason to wait 10 seconds in all cases if there is at least 2 out of 3 conditions where you could get the result immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple approach I can think of is to use [blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html). Declare method like this:

```
-(void)methodWithDelay:(void(^)(BOOL result))aCompletion
{
    if(condition 1)
    {
        aCompletion(YES);
    }
    else
    {
        if(condition 2 )
        {
            //after 10 sec delay call condition 3 which will return BOOL value
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10.f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                aCompletion(YES/NO);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            aCompletion(NO);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
[self methodWithDelay:^(BOOL result) {

    //do what you want with the result

}];
```

Please note the provided documentation about blocks, and how to avoid memory problems with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a code like this:

```
dispatch_time_t x = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10.f * NSEC_PER_SEC);
```

So this will delay it by 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a BOOL after some delay using GCD API dispatch_after, which takes the delay time, queue and has a completion handler in which you can execute the code which needs to be executed after the specified delay duration is over.

Foe example -

```
if(condition 1)
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   if(condition 2 )
   {
       //after 10 sec delay call condition 3 which will return BOOL value 
       //retutn that BOOL value after 10 sec
       double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
       dispatch_time_t delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
                    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                        return YES;//return NO;
                    });

   }
   else
   {
     return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: When I try to implement this, I get an error: Incompatible block pointer types passing'BOOL' to parameter of type 'dispatch_block_t' (aka 'void(^)(void'))

Answer (score 0):

You can use countdown timer so it won't affect on your UI and after delay, it will call your method "callYourBooleabMethod()" on onFnished.

```
      new CountDownTimer(DELAY,Interval) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                callYourBooleabMethod();
            }
        }.start();
```